# Question on Gÿongy' lemma proof

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I have some questions regarding a proof of Gÿongy's lemma given in [1](http://www.lukoe.com/finance/quantNotes/Gyongy_s_lemma_.html)

I would like to understand the following passage:
$$
\int_{s=t_0}^{s=t}\mathbb{E}\left[\delta(X_s-K)\langle dX_s\rangle^2 \right]=
\int_{s=t_0}^{s=t}\mathbb{E}\left[\delta(X_s-K) \right] \mathbb{E}\left[\langle dX_s\rangle^2|X_s=K \right]
$$

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If $X_s \neq K $  then the delta function gives zero, and the product is zero. So the term only contributes when $X_s=K$.

Re-comment, the key to understanding this is the conditional expectation:

$ E \left[ dX_s^2 \mid X_s=K \right] =\frac{E\left[ dX_s^2 \delta(X_s-K)\right]}{E\left [\delta(X_s-K)\right] }$

Where it might be helpful if you interpret the delta as indicator of $X_s=K$

Comment: What I don't understand if why the expectation of a product equals the product of expectations. Is this true because the quadratic variation $\langle dX_s\rangle^2$ is independant from $X_s$ ?

Comment: Added further explanation in the answer.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks